# sequential running of multiple functions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, pipeline

I have a series of steps (functions) which I need to run on raw dataset to prepare the dataset for modeling.
I want to concatenate all the cleaning steps one after the other and want to use each step as functions.
It is similar to sklearn Pipeline function however I don't have any fit or transform fucntion.

```
xx = [2,3,4]
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('double', double(xx)),
    ('triple', triple(xx))
])

predicted = pipeline.fit(xx).predict(xx)
```

I tried using reduce and lambda function from functools -

```
from functools import reduce
xx = 4
pipeline = [lambda x: x * 3, lambda x: x + 1, lambda x: x / 2]
val = reduce(lambda x, f: f(x), pipeline, xx)
print(val)
```

Is there a better way of accomplishing this - making code modular and automated running for multiple datasets. As of now I work on Jupyter notebook.
I can always add new functions / modify functions.. without impacting others. Please suggest.

Comment: nothing is really bad in your approach. Except I would operate on **named** functions and **not** keep them in a  mutable list

Comment: 1. I agree -  I also used named functions. The above example is just to show!

I would like to give functions in a pipeline and want to avoid providing the input parameters to each function while creating a pipeline - Any ideas.
What is the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you could use functions to achieve that, although less fancy, but powerful never the less.

Let's say you have a couple of preprocessing steps, `pre_step1`, `pre_step2`, etc. You could define a function called `pipeline`, and feed the returned value of previous step to the next function within `pipeline`. Code snippet is as follows:

```
def preprocessing_step1(rawdata):
  # do something here
  return processed_data

def preprocessing_step2(rawdata):
  # do something here
  return processed_data

def preprocessing_step3(rawdata):
  # do something here
  return processed_data

def pipeline(rawdata):
  # run steps sequentially
  data = preprocessing_step1(rawdata)
  data = preprocessing_step2(data)
  processed_data = preprocessing_step3(data)

  return processed_data
```

If you find this helpful, I could show you how to go through all datasets that you have using generator function in Python.

Comment: sounds good, looking for a any other way of creating pipeline if possible. In current pipeline function suggested, we need to give output of 1 layer as input to another .. However, definitely a simple elegant solution. Thanks!